# How to take n element from JSON in swig template

Tags: json, swig-template

I'm total newbie...

I've got some JSON

```
{
    "article": [
        {
            "id": "21",
            "type": "news",
            "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "url": "http://www....",
            "website": "www...",
            "authors": [],
            "images": [
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "dateCreated": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "path": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "type": "news",
            "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "url": "http://www....",
            "website": "www...",
            "authors": [],
            "images": [
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "dateCreated": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "path": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "23",
            "type": "news",
            "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "url": "http://www....",
            "website": "www...",
            "authors": [],
            "images": [
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "dateCreated": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "path": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This JSON have more than 3 elements. 
I dont know how to template in such order 2,3,1,4,5,6,7,8,...

How to loop once template whith json, and place value of properties in my html tags?

I want to have

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img scr="path to object 2">
    <a href="path to object 2">title of object 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img scr="path to object 3">
    <a href="path to object 3">title of object 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img scr="path to object 1">
    <a href="path to object 1">title of object 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img scr="path to object 4">
    <a href="path to object 4">title of object 4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img scr="path to object 5">
    <a href="path to object 5">title of object 5</a>
  </li>
  ...
  <li>
    <img scr="path to object n">
    <a href="path to object n">title of object n</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any sugestion?

Comment: Have you tried using for loops? http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#for

Comment: OK, I've added   {% for article in articles %}{% if loop.index == 2 %}<li><img scr="{{ article.images.path }}"><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></li>{% endif %}{% endfor %}

{{ article.title }} and {{ article.url }} works but {{ article.images.path }} doesn't work. 

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for article in articles %}
  {% if loop.index == 2 %}
    <li>
      <img src="{{ article.images[0].path }}" />
      <a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for article in articles %}
  {% if loop.index == 3 %}
    <li>
      <img src="{{ article.images[0].path }}" />
      <a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for article in articles %}
  {% if loop.index == 1 %}
    <li>
      <img src="{{ article.images[0].path }}" />
      <a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and so on...